# Como hacer una condicional en plantilla html de django. Python

Tags: html, python, django

Tengo una data como esta la cual la pinto dentro de un html para luego pasarla a un pdf por medio de weasyprint:

```
listaFinal= [
   [
      {
         "bloqueAtr":"Articulos"
      },
      {
         "":"Titulo Articulo",
         "Pais":"Turquia",
         "Abstract":"El pruebas.",
         "Keywords":"pruebas",
         "Link Articulo":"",
      },
   ],
   [
      {
         "bloqueAtr":"Proyectos"
      },
      {
         "":"Test nombre proyecto",
         "Fecha Inicio":"2005-02-01",
         "codigo_proyecto":"",
         "descripcion":"Asadsadsadsadsa sadsadsadsa",
         "tipo_proyecto":65,
      },
      {
         "":"Diferentes Investigaciones ",
         "Fecha Inicio":"2005-02-01",
         "codigo_proyecto":"",
         "descripcion":"Asadsadsadsadsa sadsadsadsa",
         "tipo_proyecto":65,
      }
   ],
]
```

En el html hago lo siguiente para recorrer los datos y poder plasmarlos en el pdf:

```
<div id="informacionDatos">
      {% for lista in listaFinal %}
        {% for i in lista %} 
          {% for clave, valor in i.items %}
            {% if clave == bloqueAtr %}
                 <h4> <b>{{ valor }}</b> </h4>
            {% endif %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
              <h3> {% if clave %}<b>{{ clave }}</b>: {% endif %}  {{ valor }}</h3>
            {% else %}
               {% if clave %}<b>{{ clave }}</b>: {% endif %}  {{ valor }}
            {% endif %}
            <br>
          {% endfor %} 
          <p> &nbsp; </p>
        {% endfor %} 
      {% endfor %} 
</div>
```

Quiero que si la clave es igual a bloqueAtr en:

```
 {% if clave == bloqueAtr %}
    <h4> <b>{{ valor }}</b> </h4>
 {% endif %}
```

Solo me muestre el valor que en este caso seria *Articulos* y *Proyectos* Pero así como lo estoy haciendo no ocurre nada y en mi pdf me devuelve clave y valor, por ejemplo  `bloqueAtr: Articulos` como lo siguiente:

```
bloqueAtr: Articulos

Titulo Articulo

Pais: Turquia
Abstract: El pruebas.
Keywords: pruebas
Link Articulo:

   
bloqueAtr: Proyectos
    
Test nombre proyecto

Fecha Inicio: 2005-02-01,
codigo_proyecto:
descripcion: Asadsadsadsadsa sadsadsadsa
tipo_proyecto: 65

Diferentes Investigaciones

Fecha Inicio: 2005-02-01,
codigo_proyecto:
descripcion: Asadsadsadsadsa sadsadsadsa
tipo_proyecto: 65
```

Y asi sucesivamente, pero yo quiero que cuando la clave sea igual a bloqueAtr me pueda devolver en el pdf algo como esto:

```
Articulos --> Negrita

Titulo Articulo

Pais: Turquia
Abstract: El pruebas.
Keywords: pruebas
Link Articulo:


Proyectos --> Negrita

Test nombre proyecto

Fecha Inicio: 2005-02-01,
codigo_proyecto:
descripcion: Asadsadsadsadsa sadsadsadsa
tipo_proyecto: 65

Diferentes Investigaciones

Fecha Inicio: 2005-02-01,
codigo_proyecto:
descripcion: Asadsadsadsadsa sadsadsadsa
tipo_proyecto: 65
```

Como puedo hacer para que si la clave es igual a bloqueAtr yo pueda manejar el valor para darle los estilos que yo quiera y mostrarlo sin su clave? Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que `bloqueAtr` esta siendo tomada como una variable, no como una cadena. Es por eso que esa comparación es siempre falsa. Agrega comillas en el if y creo que se solucionaría.